# How to define custom range in Python Pandas usecols property

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python (just installed yday) and am workink with Pandas, obviously, also new. I have a large csv file I am trying to read and then send to a MySQL database. The problem is, the file contains some header information and I need to pull in the table inside the data…say, data starting at row 40 (I believe I can handle this with the skiprows property. I also need to grab, say…columns 9-80. I know there’s the usecols property, but I’m only seeing it used where you specify the name of the column. Questions

1. is there any way to specify a range?
2. I haven’t researched this yet, but could you please refer me to what to look up to xfer the data to MySQL please?

Thank you!

Comment: ,You don't need to specify the name of the columns, usecols accepts integers too. You  can create a list [9, 10, ..., 80] and assign it to usecols property in pd.read_csv method

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=40, usecols=[*range(9,81)])
```

just pay attention to the column's index. In Python the first column(or row) has index 0, so the tenth column has index 9.